# Issues with TLS connection in Golang

Tags: ssl, https, go, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have the following certificate hierarchy:

Root-->CA-->3 leaf certificates

The entire chain has both serverAuth and clientAuth as extended key usages explicitly defined.

In my go code, I create a tls.Config object like so:

```
func parseCert(certFile, keyFile string) (cert tls.Certificate, err error) {
    certPEMBlock , err := ioutil.ReadFile(certFile)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    var certDERBlock *pem.Block
    for {
        certDERBlock, certPEMBlock = pem.Decode(certPEMBlock)
        if certDERBlock == nil {
            break
        }
        if certDERBlock.Type == "CERTIFICATE" {
            cert.Certificate = append(cert.Certificate, certDERBlock.Bytes)
        }
    }

    // Need to flip the array because openssl gives it to us in the opposite format than golang tls expects.
    cpy := make([][]byte, len(cert.Certificate))
    copy(cpy, cert.Certificate)

    var j = 0
    for i := len(cpy)-1; i >=0; i-- {
        cert.Certificate[j] = cert.Certificate[i]
        j++
    }

    keyData, err := ioutil.ReadFile(keyFile)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode(keyData)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    ecdsaKey, err := x509.ParseECPrivateKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    cert.PrivateKey = ecdsaKey

    return
}

// configure and create a tls.Config instance using the provided cert, key, and ca cert files.
func configureTLS(certFile, keyFile, caCertFile string) (tlsConfig *tls.Config, err error) {

    c, err := parseCert(certFile, keyFile)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    ciphers := []uint16 {
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    }

    certPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(caCertFile)
    if nil != err {
        log.Println("failed to load ca cert")
        log.Fatal(seelog.Errorf("failed to load ca cert.\n%s", err))
    }

    if !certPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(buf) {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to parse truststore")
    }


    tlsConfig = &tls.Config {
        CipherSuites: ciphers,
        ClientAuth: tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
        PreferServerCipherSuites: true,
        RootCAs: certPool,
        ClientCAs: certPool,
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{c},
    }

    return
}
```

certFile is the certificate chain file and keyFile is the private key file. caCertFile is the truststore and consists of just the root certificate

So basically, here is what I expect to have inside of my tls.Config object that comes out of this function:

RootCAs: Just the root certificate from caCertFile
ClientCAs: Again, just the root certificate from caCertFile, same as RootCAs
Certificates: A single certificate chain, containing all of the certificates in certFile, ordered to be leaf first.

Now, I have 3 pieces here. A server, a relay, and a client. The client connects directly to the relay, which in turn forwards the request to the server. All three pieces use the same configuration code, of course using different certs/keys. The caCertFile is the same between all 3 pieces.

Now, if I stand up the server and the relay and connect to the relay from my browser, all goes well, so I can assume that the connection between relay and server is fine. The issue comes about when I try to connect my client to the relay. When I do so, the TLS handshake fails and the following error is returned:

**x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**

On the relay side of things, I get the following error:
**http: TLS handshake error from : remote error: bad certificate**

I am really at a loss here. I obviously have something setup incorrectly, but I am not sure what. It's really weird that it works from the browser (meaning that the config is correct from relay to server), but it doesn't work with the same config from my client.

### Update:

So if I add `InsecureSkipVerify: true` to my tls.Config object on both the relay and the client, the errors change to:

on the client: **remote error: bad certificate**

and on the relay: **http: TLS handshake error from : tls: client didn't provide a certificate**

So it looks like the client is rejecting the certificate on from the server (the relay) due to it being invalid for some reason and thus never sending its certificate to the server (the relay).

I really wish go had better logging. I can't even hook into this process to see what, exactly, is going on.

Comment: Can you try to get the individual pieces working first, and see what part is actually failing? Connect with TLS (no verification, no client auth), then connect with TLS+Verification, on only then try to connect with TLS+Verification+ClientAuth?

Comment: Can you try to specify which code is the server vs. client vs. relay? Otherwise it's difficult to tell where the problem lies.

Comment: How is your client code consuming the tls.config you create?

Answer (score 4):

When you say

> Need to flip the array because openssl gives it to us in the opposite format than golang tls expects.

I have used certificates generated by openssl and had no problem opening them with:

```
tls.LoadX509KeyPair(cert, key)
```

Anyway, the error message **bad certificate** is due to the server not managing to match the client-provided certificate against its RootCAs. I have also had this problem in Go using self-signed certificats and the only work-around I've found is to install the *caCertFile* into the machines system certs, and use `x509.SystemCertPool()` instead of `x509.NewCertPool()`.
Maybe someone else will have another solution?

Comment: This was such a life saver ! Helped me fix the issue while using custom CA and certificates with `go-dqlite`.

Answer (score 0):

Beside what beldin0 suggested.
I have tried another way to do this.

```
caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(crt)

client := &http.Client{
  //some config
  Transport: &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
      RootCAs: caCertPool,
    },
  },
}
```

Here, the variable "crt" is the content in your certificate.
Basically, you just add it into your code(or read as a config file).
Then everything would be fine.